# Finding the Kolmogorov's Backward equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

SO this question is probably really easy, I am just struggling in understanding how to do it

It goes like this: we have a system with 3 components, at time $t=0$, component 1 is active and the other two are not. When 1 fails then 2 becomes active, when 2 fails then 3 becomes active. When 3 fails than all the parts are replaced and 1 is active again. Let $T_k$ be the lifetime of component $k$, then $\quad T_k\sim Exp(\lambda_k), \quad$ and $\quad \forall j,i \quad$ $T_j$ and $T_i$ are independent.
Let the number of the component that is active be the state number, denoted by $X_t$ where $t$ is time. Then write Kolmogorov backward equations.

Now I am not sure how to write $X_t$ in general as $T_k$ is exponential so naturally I don't know to get Kolmogorov's equation. (All I know is discrete time markov chains, I am tying to study ahead on continuous time markov chains)

All that I know is that  (sorry I don't know how to properly draw circles and such in mathjax)
$$(1) \rightarrow^{\lambda_1}  (2)\rightarrow^{\lambda_2}  (3)\rightarrow^{\lambda_3}  (1)$$
and that $Pr(X_0=1)=1$. As well as that the generating matrix is
$$
G=
\begin{bmatrix}
        -\lambda_1 & \lambda_1 & 0 \\
        0 & -\lambda_2 & \lambda_2 \\
        \lambda_3 & 0 & -\lambda_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: You did not explain what happens after component 3 fails.

Comment: @Did you are right, I added it (my bad).
When 3 fails, then all the parts are replaced and 1 is active again.

Comment: Right. Now you might want to work on your title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to answer this myself, unless someone can explain better than me, I will have my answer being selected here.

Since I know the Generating matrix is:
$$
G=
\begin{bmatrix}
        -\lambda_1 & \lambda_1 & 0 \\
        0 & -\lambda_2 & \lambda_2 \\
        \lambda_3 & 0 & -\lambda_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And Kolmogorov backward equations is given by $ \frac{dp_ij(t)}{dt} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty v_{ik}p_{kj} $.

Where $p_{ij}(t)$ is the probability of moving from state i to j at time t. And  $v_{ij}$ is the infinitesimal parameter (which is given by the Generating matrix) of jump i to j.

You can show that: 
$$
\forall j, \quad \frac{dp_{1j}(t)}{dt} = -\lambda_1 p_{1j} + \lambda_1 p_{2j} \\ \
 \quad \frac{dp_{2j}(t)}{dt} = -\lambda_2 p_{2j} + \lambda_2 p_{3j} \\ \
 \quad \frac{dp_{3j}(t)}{dt} = \lambda_3 p_{1j} - \lambda_3 p_{3j} 
$$
Kolmogorov backward equations^ for all i,j .